# Can't set a discord bots custom status

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using the discord.js library and I can't find anything useful about how to set a bots custom status. Only how to set it to online, idle, DnD, and offline.

I attempted to do this anyway, I used this code:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
 client.user.setPresence({
   status: "online", 
   game: {
     name: "Type BotCommands", 
     type: "PLAYING" 
   }
  });
 });
```

nodemon gives no errors but the custom status doesn't show up. I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setActivity
[discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)